# Pandas create new column referencing another column in another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to add another column to `df2` referencing `df1`

```
>>> df1
    col1  col2
0     A   Name A
1     B   Name B


>>> df2
    col1  col2
0     A   12.3
1     B   34.0
2     A   103.2
```

so that `col1` in `df2` is used to get the `col2` value from `df1`, i.e. to produce:

```
>>> df2
    col1  col2   col3 
0     A   12.3   Name A
1     B   34.0   Name B
2     A   103.2  Name A
```

(I can do it with creating an empty column in `df2` and then iterating over rows such as `for n in range(0,df.shape[0])…then iloc`, but apparently this is bad practice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two dataframes

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1, how='left', on='col1')
```

Input:

```
df1
  col1   col2
0    A  NameA
1    B  NameB

df2
  col1   col3
0    A   12.3
1    B   34.0
2    A  103.2
```

Output:

```
  col1   col3   col2
0    A   12.3  NameA
1    B   34.0  NameB
2    A  103.2  NameA
```